# Tortoise HG bisect menus in version 2.10

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

Where is an bisect menu in `Tortoise HG`? 
How to use bisect from GUI?
I have version `2.10`.

Or I could use bisect only from console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `Bisect` option in the `Repository` menu, or you can select two changesets and right-click to obtain the `Bisect` in the context menu.